# c++: способ передать параметры для конструктора

Tags: c++, наследование, шаблоны-с++, конструктор, параметры

заранее извиняюсь за большую портянку в вопросе

Подскажите как более правильно и красиво реализовать следующий функционал:

***предыстория***

у меня обрабатывается массив разношерстных объектов (отвечающих за разные статистики)

```
std::vector<...> objects;
```

, объединённых некоторым общим минимальным функционалом (`.add`, `.get`, `.save` и т.п.) поэтому хотя упомянутые объекты принадлежат разным классам, я их всех унаследовал от одного базового абстрактного класса, задающего упомянутый минимальный функционал

```
std::vector<IBaseStatistics*> objects;
object[0]->add(12.75); // пример использования
```

Каждый класс объектов (статистик) обладает своими начальными входными параметров, которые задаются при создании:

```
objects.push_back(new CStatistics1(1, "data", true));
objects.push_back(new CStatistics2(L"unicode", 3.1415);
```

***задача 1***

Но вот у меня возникла потребность в новом классе, который содержит массив старого класса заданного вида, т.е.

```
class CStatictics_new: public IBaseStatistics
{
    protected:
        std::vector<CStatistics1> m_inner;
}
```

При этом новый класс требует как своих начальных входных параметров, так и входных параметров используемого в массиве класса (`CStatistics1`).

***И у меня встал вопрос - как правильнее задавать эти входные параметры для класса CStatistics1?***

В голову приходит 2 способа (использовал первый):

1) задавать параметры для обоих классов в конструкторе "главного" класса, т.е.:

```
objects.push_back(new CStatistics_new(
    value1, value2,
    1, "data", true
));
```

хранить полученные параметры класса `CStatistics1` как члены класса `CStatistics_new` и когда требуется пополнять массив `m_inner` использовать их

2) в классе `CStatistics1` хранить параметры как члены класса, добавить некоторый метод `clone`, чтобы создавать копии класса и передать в класс `CStatistics_new` созданный вне этого класса объект класса `CStatistics1`

***Как лучше поступить? Может есть 3 способ, более правильный и лучший, чем те, которые привёл выше***?

***задача 2***

впоследствии оказалось, что класс `CStatistics_new` нужен для работы и с другими типами и я его сделал просто шаблонным

```
template <class ICustomStatistics>
class CStatictics_new: public IBaseStatistics
{
    protected:
        std::vector<ICustomStatistics> m_inner;
}
```

но после этого возникли проблемы с передачей параметров для класса `ICustomStatistics` в конструкторе класса `CStatictics_new`
и первый описанный метод уже не работает, т.е. остается только второй

***Что можно сделать в этом случае?***

P.S.

т.е. основной вопрос - способ передавать разные параметры для классов внутри других классов

Answer (score 0):

Базовый класс:

```
class IStatistic
{
public:
    virtual ~IStatistic() = default;
};
```

Наследник:

```
class OrderStatistic : public IStatistic
{
public:
    explicit OrderStatistic(std::size_t) {}
};
```

Здесь для нас важно только непосредственно наличие параметра в конструкторе.

Аггрегатор:

```
template<typename Statistic>
class StatisticAggregator : public IStatistic
{
public:
    template<typename... Args>
    explicit StatisticAggregator(std::string description, Args&&... args)
        : m_prototype(std::forward<Args>(args)...)
        , m_items()
        , m_description(std::move(description))
    {}

protected:
    Statistic               m_prototype;
    std::vector<Statistic>  m_items;
    std::string             m_description;
};
```

В данном классе:

1. m_prototype - это объект типа `Statistic`, который Вы инициализируете при вызове конструктора `StatisticAggregator` и впоследствии будете использовать его копии для своих целей, о которых я не могу знать, потому что Вы не рассказывали :)
2. m_items - контейнер с объектами типа `Statistic`
3. m_description - собственный data-member класса `StatisticAggregator`

Пример:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<IStatistic>> m_data;
    m_data.push_back(std::make_unique<StatisticAggregator<OrderStatistic>>("orders", 10));
}
```

Касательно конструктора `StatisticAggregator`: сперва перечислены аргументы, которые будут использованы для инициализации полей самого класса (m_description), а затем `args` - аргументы, которые потребуется для конструктора объекта типа `Statistic`.